# Como diseñar el efecto degradado sobre una imagen en android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, apk

[image: Planes para correr]

Existe alguna manera de colocar un degradado que vaya acorde al color dominante de una foto en xml?

Comment: Hola, nuevamente te recordamos que es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, si deseas una opinión puedes preguntar en [chat], saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero te sirva, podrías crear en tu carpeta drawable un archivo `</shape>` que nos de el degradado como este:

```
<gradient android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#00ffffff"
    android:startColor="#aa000000"/>
```

Posteriormente en tu layout crear un `<View` en el cual uses como `background` el gradiente que realizaste junto a la imagen a usar:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Ya puedes poner un texto en color blanco sobre la imagen y ya debería resaltar como en tu foto.

Saludos!!